# Determine generator over $GF(2^4)$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

Working in $GF(2^4$) Field generated modulus $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. Find a generator of $F$.

What I have figured out so far - $16$ polynomials to consider. If $b$ is generator then start with $b = x + 1$. Compute $b^2, b^3, ...$ and if any one evaluates to non-zero then we got a problem => not a generator. Does this continue until a generator polynomial is found or is there a better way?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your formatting has been corrupted and you might want to fix this. Regards

Comment: No. I want to know how many generators are possible (I believe 4) and any one of the generator polynomials.

Comment: @user100503 There are $8 = \varphi(15)$ generators

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction as to how can I reason into concluding that and finding one of those generators.

Comment: A cyclic group of order 15 has $\phi(15)=8$ generators, so a random pick will work with probability $8/16$. Assuming that you know enough not to try $0,1,$ or a any of the powers of $x$ improves the odds to $8/10$. The two remaining elements that you want to miss are those of order three. Your $b=x+1$ is not a power of $x$. Its order is thus either three or fifteen. Can you rule out three?

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you to everyone who helped. I appreciate it.